# The text box for for editing one's nomination should be a bit bigger

Tags: bug, moderator-election

Currently the text box that appears when editing one's nomination(https://stackoverflow.com/election/nomination-edit/6/**YOUR_USERID**) appears like this:

[image: SCREENSHOT]

The red freehand circles show the problem. The size of the text box and the preview box needs to be increased.

Comment: Needs a hand-drawn vertical line with horizontal arrows illustrating the gap.

Comment: I had to zoom in to see that one, but yeah it should be bigger. Good eyesight, I would have never caught that.

Comment: Complaining about any aspect of the election automatically disqualifies you.

Comment: @Mooseman , I wasn't going to nominate myself anyway! :p